# Good online poker app to play with friends?

Tags: software

I am looking for a good online poker application/website simply for playing heads up with my friends for fun. A few friends and I use the game-pigeon poker app in apple i-message for our phones, but I find that it is very slow to have to send texts back and forth even for the smallest action. Is there any "for fun" online poker app preferably not on mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On like Play WSOP you can join a table with your friend but you don't get heads up.

Are you a programmer? It would be pretty easy to build one. Problem is dealer could hack and see the cards. Don't even need a database.

For security would need an external server to be the dealer. So there is a cost of hosting but that is pretty cheap.

I started to write one for Windows Store (both mobile and PC). Do you think you would pay for the app. Entry level only get to play against a random player.

For an upgrade fee it would store all your hands, give you statistics, and private games. It would also have a learn mode to give you outs and pot odds for calling.

It would not support real money but if you and you friend agreed to a cash transaction that is not my business.

When I searched to market there was nothing like this in the Windows Store.

Comment: I am studying to be a programmer, sounds like a fun project actually. I don't think I would personally pay for an app like that but that is not to say that others wouldn't.

Comment: Ouch.  That is why I did not do it.  Most people do not even want to pay $1.

Comment: @Clarko If you look on codereview you will see some of my poker tools.

Answer (score 1):

Pokerstars have a system called Home Games, or Clubs I believe and you can create a house group where your friends can join and setup a game for play money or real money etc. It's pretty good I use it with my uni mates over summer when we all go back home. Hope it helps

Comment: is this available in the USA?

Comment: @Clarko I think it is but you can only use play money but i'm not sure